# AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'hold'

Tags: python-3.x

I change a new computer and install Python3.6 and matplotlib，When I run the code last month in the old computer, I get the following error:
ax.hold(True)
AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'hold'

Answer (score 8):

The `Axes.hold` method was [deprecated since 2.0](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.hold.html) and was removed in matplotlib3.0:

> Deprecated since version 2.0: axes.hold is deprecated. See the API Changes document (http://matplotlib.org/api/api_changes.html) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

The API Changes document says:
Setting or unsetting hold (deprecated in version 2.0) has now been completely removed. Matplotlib now always behaves as if hold=True. To clear an axes you can manually use cla(), or to clear an entire figure use clf().